# How to I combine closed and open poly surfaces in Rhino Mac?

Tags: surface, rhino3d

I have a number of closed poly surfaces and I creates a few more surfaces using loft, as illustrated in the photos. Is there an easy way to turn this into a one closed poly-surface, I'm a little confused.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To join surfaces that share an edge, use the Join command. To union closed polysurfaces (solids) use the BooleanUnion command.

Comment: for some reason it never actually registers as closed